# How to hide address bar without cutting off footer

Tags: javascript, css, dreamweaver, mobile-browser

```
{% if is_mobile % }
  // Hides mobile browser's address bar when page is done loading.
  window.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
    setTimeout(function() { window.scrollTo(0, 1); }, 0);
  }, false);
{% endif % }
```

This code hides the address bar, but it reduces the size of my footer as well which affects my content.How can I block address bar without changing my other settings? I'm using Dreamweaver.

Comment: What does "reduces the size of my footer" mean? The phone's browser's chrome?

Comment: Dreamweaver has nothing to do with your code other then being a editor not to recommend.